# Fill ParametricPlot3D into 3D solid shape

Tags: plotting, regions, coordinate-transformation, geometric-transform, opencascade

i have data point and transform it with matrix and plot with `ParametricPlot3D` and look like this

[image]

my goals is to fill this and get the centroid with `RegionControid` also moment of `MomentOfInertia`

this is my code

*Data Point*

```
FitRS1q = {{10.` - 0.04789494889653917` u + 
     6.106226635438361`*^-16 u^2 - 0.012715436672561739` u^3, 
    0.` - 1.0011358892218931` u + 2.220446049250313`*^-16 u^2 + 
     0.0016685598153607373` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {9.863613034027223` - 
     0.1519481386239202` u - 0.06300194626890193` u^2 + 
     0.003855148890327287` u^3, -1.6459459028073389` - 
     0.9874817005762238` u + 0.008267314646035917` u^2 + 
     0.0016230458532625613` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {9.458172417006347` - 
     0.32850699444717457` u - 0.043900605945204285` u^2 - 
     0.0002503040173415516` u^3, -3.2469946920468344` - 
     0.9468915853112144` u + 0.016309118500075215` u^2 + 
     0.001533259430982703` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {8.794737512064891` - 
     0.4755666189686845` u - 0.045140802460473584` u^2 + 
     0.0011630214255688998` u^3, -4.759473930370735` - 
     0.880472735962083` u + 0.023906052115064913` u^2 + 
     0.0014016496893576313` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466475`}, {7.891405093963936` - 
     0.6151572780042756` u - 0.03937830957484745` u^2 + 
     0.0010676998962897422` u^3, -6.142127126896678` - 
     0.7900368855932105` u + 0.030850890950785415` u^2 + 
     0.0012318065942124035` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {6.77281571625741` - 
     0.7364934582587188` u - 0.034088112059057485` u^2 + 
     0.0013389947055288953` u^3, -7.357239106731316` - 
     0.6780508884720549` u + 0.03695419788869647` u^2 + 
     0.0010283630405246713` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {5.469481581224268` - 
     0.8381351320272548` u - 0.027453713676646174` u^2 + 
     0.0014677263755578096` u^3, -8.371664782625285` - 
     0.5475694306069663` u + 0.04204949069636488` u^2 + 
     0.0007968683705859569` u^3, 
    1.651586909446646`}, {4.016954246529695` - 
     0.9168087954409115` u - 0.020181480671083385` u^2 + 
     0.0015848373043033659` u^3, -9.157733266550574` - 
     0.40215170628030433` u + 0.04599778280459976` u^2 + 
     0.0005436374075032946` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466467`}, {2.454854871407991` - 
     0.9705026649304699` u - 0.012328991034913805` u^2 + 
     0.0016510968242356983` u^3, -9.694002659393304` - 
     0.2457643309970889` u + 0.048691376081753834` u^2 + 
     0.00027557669144763486` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {0.8257934547233232` - 
     0.9977161801472793` u - 0.004148201331503509` u^2 + 
     0.0016743884327814484` u^3, -9.965844930066698` - 
     0.082673148187592` u + 0.05005679265018392` u^2 + 
     1.7295139244366542`*^-9 u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {-0.8257934547233232` - 
     0.9977165246885812` u + 0.0041479927192291655` u^2 + 
     0.0016513494446379617` u^3, -9.965844930066698` + 
     0.08267315290525513` u + 0.05005680121951156` u^2 - 
     0.0002755836095033326` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {-2.454854871407991` - 
     0.9705016313065639` u + 0.012330034096285969` u^2 + 
     0.001583826822694423` u^3, -9.694002659393304` + 
     0.24576430740877317` u + 0.048691350373770925` u^2 - 
     0.00054361319430829` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466467`}, {-4.016954246529695` - 
     0.9168125853952338` u + 0.020177517037863968` u^2 + 
     0.0014715156815914288` u^3, -9.157733266550574` + 
     0.402151795915904` u + 0.045997877067204596` u^2 - 
     0.0007969583053102358` u^3, 
    1.651586909446646`}, {-5.469481581224268` - 
     0.8381210058338714` u + 0.02746852514815057` u^2 + 
     0.0013248479630036947` u^3, -8.371664782625285` + 
     0.547569095652883` u + 0.04204913935393062` u^2 - 
     0.001028027514822727` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {-6.77281571625741` - 
     0.7365461730779306` u + 0.034032829806261766` u^2 + 
     0.0011204975603569811` u^3, -7.357239106731316` + 
     0.6780521386527881` u + 0.03695550899583333` u^2 - 
     0.0012330587622961797` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {-7.891405093963936` - 
     0.6149605449208121` u + 0.03958462711452171` u^2 + 
     0.0009659775118251446` u^3, -6.142127126896678` + 
     0.7900322198243604` u + 0.030845997864674235` u^2 - 
     0.0013969765427244152` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466475`}, {-8.794737512064891` - 
     0.4763008364833263` u + 0.04437081455457159` u^2 + 
     0.0004850739735662857` u^3, -4.759473930370735` + 
     0.8804901488567499` u + 0.023924313352371662` u^2 - 
     0.0015506998494315694` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466462`}, {-9.458172417006347` - 
     0.32576685747207135` u + 0.046774240029138214` u^2 + 
     0.001110680840439554` u^3, -3.2469946920468344` + 
     0.946826599501397` u + 0.01624096663696495` u^2 - 
     0.0015579573261003121` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {-9.863613034027223` - 
     0.16217446900969162` u + 0.05227739783907004` u^2 - 
     0.0024729424639187425` u^3, -1.6459459028073389` + 
     0.987724230920827` u + 0.008521660861173785` u^2 - 
     0.0019114735055607568` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {-10.` - 0.009729764328556751` u + 
     0.040024559635400185` u^2 - 0.040176377218310015` u^3, 
    0.` + 1.0002307536532973` u - 0.0009492329974403191` u^2 + 
     0.0009528335432911206` u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` + 0.002607082494839741` u - 
     0.010724548429833515` u^2 + 0.010765227823399186` u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735` + 0.9999381697449593` u + 
     0.0002543462151374243` u^2 - 0.000255310978612755` u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` - 0.0006985656508022121` u + 
     0.0028736340839338763` u^2 - 0.002884534075286729` u^3, 
    0.8421052631578947` + 1.0000165673668655` u - 
     0.0000681518631111544` u^2 + 0.00006841037116345206` u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` + 0.00018718010836910778` u - 
     0.000769987905901992` u^2 + 0.0007729084777477325` u^3, 
    1.263157894736842` + 0.9999955607875789` u + 
     0.000018261237305416955` u^2 - 0.000018330506037500527` u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` - 0.00005015478267421893` u + 
     0.00020631753967409103` u^2 - 0.00020709983570420005` u^3, 
    1.6842105263157894` + 1.000001189482819` u - 
     4.893086110513423`*^-6 u^2 + 4.911652988326409`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` + 0.00001343902232776795` u - 
     0.00005528225279437223` u^2 + 0.000055490865069067946` u^3, 
    2.1052631578947367` + 0.9999996812811457` u + 
     1.311107135748557`*^-6 u^2 - 1.316105908699683`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` - 3.6013066368528564`*^-6 u + 
     0.000014811471503397812` u^2 - 0.00001486362457207166` u^3, 
    2.526315789473684` + 1.000000085392599` u - 
     3.5134243603351933`*^-7 u^2 + 3.527706571304634`*^-7 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` + 9.66204219643476`*^-7 u - 
     3.963633219219022`*^-6 u^2 + 3.963633219218696`*^-6 u^3, 
    2.9473684210526314` + 0.9999999771484593` u + 
     9.426260483280657`*^-8 u^2 - 9.497671626945703`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` - 2.635102417210479`*^-7 u + 
     1.0430613734782786`*^-6 u^2 - 9.909083048031263`*^-7 u^3, 
    3.3684210526315788` + 1.0000000060135634` u - 
     2.570798329770696`*^-8 u^2 + 2.7136202618294192`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` + 8.783674724071528`*^-8 u - 
     2.0861227469409112`*^-7 u^2 - 6.1932931520866305`*^-18 u^3, 
    3.789473684210526` + 0.9999999987972872` u + 
     8.569328358021266`*^-9 u^2 - 1.3568101309147096`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.` - 8.783674724181325`*^-8 u - 
     2.0861227470191413`*^-7 u^2 + 9.909083048278974`*^-7 u^3, 
    4.2105263157894735` + 0.9999999987972877` u - 
     8.569321252593909`*^-9 u^2 + 2.7136197289223674`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {-10.` + 2.635102417265378`*^-7 u + 
     1.043061373501747`*^-6 u^2 - 3.963633219305407`*^-6 u^3, 
    4.631578947368421` + 1.000000006013563` u + 
     2.5707976192279602`*^-8 u^2 - 9.497673403302542`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {-10.` - 9.66204219664337`*^-7 u - 
     3.963633219305078`*^-6 u^2 + 0.000014863624572393692` u^3, 
    5.052631578947368` + 0.9999999771484596` u - 
     9.426259772737922`*^-8 u^2 + 3.527706340378245`*^-7 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {-10.` + 3.601306636930814`*^-6 u + 
     0.000014811471503718553` u^2 - 0.00005549086507026952` u^3, 
    5.473684210526316` + 1.0000000853925985` u + 
     3.5134242803991356`*^-7 u^2 - 1.3161059158051103`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {-10.` - 0.000013439022328058906` u - 
     0.000055282252795569204` u^2 + 0.00020709983570868382` u^3, 
    5.894736842105263` + 0.9999996812811456` u - 
     1.3111071304194866`*^-6 u^2 + 4.91165296523377`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {-10.` + 0.000050154782675304865` u + 
     0.000206317539678558` u^2 - 0.0007729084777644677` u^3, 
    6.315789473684211` + 1.000001189482819` u + 
     4.8930861016316385`*^-6 u^2 - 0.00001833050604105324` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {-10.` - 0.00018718010837316036` u - 
     0.0007699879059186634` u^2 + 0.0028845340753491794` u^3, 
    6.7368421052631575` + 0.999995560787579` u - 
     0.000018261237299199706` u^2 + 0.00006841037117055748` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {-10.` + 0.0006985656508173373` u + 
     0.0028736340839960934` u^2 - 0.010765227823632281` u^3, 
    7.157894736842105` + 1.0000165673668653` u + 
     0.00006815186310049626` u^2 - 0.000255310978612755` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {-10.` - 0.0026070824948961862` u - 
     0.010724548430065645` u^2 + 0.04017637721917965` u^3, 
    7.578947368421052` + 0.9999381697449603` u - 
     0.0002543462151241016` u^2 + 0.0009528335432769097` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {-10.` + 0.009729764328767385` u + 
     0.040024559636265986` u^2 + 0.002472942463316835` u^3, 
    8.` + 1.0002307536532926` u + 0.0009492329974192248` u^2 - 
     0.0019114735055461018` u^3, 
    1.651586909446647`}, {-9.863613034027223` + 
     0.1621744690078393` u + 0.052277397836953066` u^2 - 
     0.0011106808384796774` u^3, 
    9.64594590280734` + 0.9877242309208706` u - 
     0.008521660861124714` u^2 - 0.0015579573261468305` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {-9.458172417006347` + 
     0.3257668574792697` u + 0.04677424003673314` u^2 - 
     0.00048507398080377406` u^3, 
    11.246994692046835` + 0.9468265995012262` u - 
     0.016240966637143917` u^2 - 0.001550699849260151` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {-8.794737512064891` + 
     0.4763008364563855` u + 0.04437081452630576` u^2 - 
     0.0009659774848342351` u^3, 
    12.759473930370735` + 0.8804901488573894` u - 
     0.02392431335170153` u^2 - 0.0013969765433647918` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466475`}, {-7.891405093963936` + 
     0.614960545021377` u + 0.03958462721998934` u^2 - 
     0.0011204976610835748` u^3, 
    14.142127126896678` + 0.7900322198219754` u - 
     0.030845997867173125` u^2 - 0.0012330587599072018` u^3, 
    1.651586909446647`}, {-6.77281571625741` + 0.736546172702611` u + 
     0.03403282941265773` u^2 - 0.0013248475870903942` u^3, 
    15.357239106731317` + 0.6780521386616897` u - 
     0.03695550898649791` u^2 - 0.0010280275237380954` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {-5.469481581224268` + 
     0.8381210072345848` u + 0.027468526617105304` u^2 - 
     0.0014715170845193137` u^3, 
    16.371664782625285` + 0.5475690956196622` u - 
     0.04204913938876742` u^2 - 0.0007969582720376844` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466453`}, {-4.016954246529695` + 0.9168125801677` u + 
     0.020177511555649286` u^2 - 0.001583821586898182` u^3, 
    17.157733266550572` + 0.40215179603988255` u - 
     0.04599787693718782` u^2 - 0.0005436133184824332` u^3, 
    1.651586909446648`}, {-2.454854871407991` + 
     0.9705016508159835` u + 0.012330054556188408` u^2 - 
     0.0016513689848941526` u^3, 
    17.694002659393306` + 0.2457643069460834` u - 
     0.04869135085900689` u^2 - 0.00027558314608081` u^3, 
    1.651586909446646`}, {-0.8257934547233232` + 
     0.9977164518784366` u + 0.004147916361837423` u^2 - 
     0.001674315507553148` u^3, 
    17.965844930066698` + 0.08267315463203838` u - 
     0.050056799408598765` u^2 - 3.469446951953614`*^-18 u^3, 
    1.6515869094466464`}, {0.8257934547233232` + 
     0.9977164518784366` u - 0.0041479163618367565` u^2 - 
     0.0016513689848941526` u^3, 
    17.965844930066698` - 0.08267315463203838` u - 
     0.050056799408597114` u^2 + 0.00027558314608081` u^3, 
    1.651586909446646`}, {2.454854871407991` + 
     0.9705016508159836` u - 0.012330054556189296` u^2 - 
     0.001583821586898182` u^3, 
    17.694002659393306` - 0.2457643069460834` u - 
     0.048691350859002114` u^2 + 0.000543613318482461` u^3, 
    1.651586909446648`}, {4.016954246529695` + 
     0.9168125801677002` u - 0.020177511555648397` u^2 - 
     0.0014715170845194248` u^3, 
    17.157733266550572` - 0.4021517960398826` u - 
     0.04599787693718582` u^2 + 0.0007969582720376844` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466453`}, {5.469481581224268` + 
     0.8381210072345846` u - 0.027468526617105082` u^2 - 
     0.0013248475870903942` u^3, 
    16.371664782625285` - 0.547569095619662` u - 
     0.042049139388770085` u^2 + 0.0010280275237380954` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {6.77281571625741` + 
     0.7365461727026115` u - 0.034032829412656396` u^2 - 
     0.0011204976610837414` u^3, 
    15.357239106731317` - 0.6780521386616897` u - 
     0.03695550898650102` u^2 + 0.0012330587599072018` u^3, 
    1.651586909446647`}, {7.891405093963936` + 0.614960545021376` u - 
     0.039584627219990454` u^2 - 0.0009659774848331248` u^3, 
    14.142127126896678` - 0.7900322198219755` u - 
     0.030845997867174457` u^2 + 0.0013969765433647918` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466475`}, {8.794737512064891` + 
     0.47630083645638954` u - 0.04437081452630187` u^2 - 
     0.0004850739808078264` u^3, 
    12.759473930370735` - 0.8804901488573892` u - 
     0.023924313351701754` u^2 + 0.00155069984926004` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {9.458172417006347` + 
     0.32576685747925466` u - 0.04677424003674946` u^2 - 
     0.0011106808384645228` u^3, 
    11.246994692046835` - 0.9468265995012265` u - 
     0.01624096663714436` u^2 + 0.0015579573261470525` u^3, 
    1.6515869094466458`}, {9.863613034027223` + 
     0.1621744690078957` u - 0.05227739783689517` u^2 + 
     0.002472942463260297` u^3, 
    9.64594590280734` - 0.9877242309208693` u - 
     0.008521660861121605` u^2 + 0.0019114735055447696` u^3, 
    1.651586909446647`}, {10.` + 0.009729764328556762` u - 
     0.0400245596364875` u^2 + 0.040176377220892345` u^3, 
    8.` - 1.0002307536532975` u + 0.0009492329974083447` u^2 - 
     0.0009528335432378299` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {10.` - 0.002607082494381927` u + 
     0.010724548432008148` u^2 - 0.01076522783114629` u^3, 
    7.578947368421052` - 0.9999381697449484` u - 
     0.0002543462150779163` u^2 + 0.0002553109784351193` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {10.` + 0.000698565648970955` u - 
     0.0028736340915450445` u^2 + 0.002884534103692688` u^3, 
    7.157894736842105` - 1.0000165673669088` u + 
     0.00006815186292286057` u^2 - 0.00006841037049554188` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {10.` - 0.00018718010150189034` u + 
     0.0007699879341720381` u^2 - 0.0007729085836244897` u^3, 
    6.7368421052631575` - 0.9999955607874161` u - 
     0.000018261236625960464` u^2 + 0.00001833050352928467` u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {10.` + 0.00005015475703660714` u - 
     0.00020631764514310584` u^2 + 0.0002071002308052643` u^3, 
    6.315789473684211` - 1.0000011894834269` u + 
     4.8930836022975654`*^-6 u^2 - 4.911643596727799`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {10.` - 0.000013438926644538058` u + 
     0.00005528264640038614` u^2 - 0.00005549233959656957` u^3, 
    5.894736842105263` - 0.9999996812788764` u - 
     1.3110977929997603`*^-6 u^2 + 1.3160709428916562`*^-6 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {10.` + 3.6009495415451366`*^-6 u - 
     0.00001481294045843851` u^2 + 0.000014869127581013428` u^3, 
    5.473684210526316` - 1.0000000854010678` u + 
     3.5130759101775766`*^-7 u^2 - 3.5264012510083376`*^-7 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {10.` - 9.64871521642474`*^-7 u + 
     3.9691154333679446`*^-6 u^2 - 3.9841707274842844`*^-6 u^3, 
    5.052631578947368` - 0.9999999771168527` u - 
     9.413257995305457`*^-8 u^2 + 9.448966054037555`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789469`}, {10.` + 2.585365450247631`*^-7 u - 
     1.0635212750332525`*^-6 u^2 + 1.0675553289236703`*^-6 u^3, 
    4.631578947368421` - 1.0000000061315208` u + 
     2.522274478167219`*^-8 u^2 - 2.531841758468545`*^-8 u^3, 
    0.4210526315789478`}, {10.` - 6.927465845657743`*^-8 u + 
     2.849696667650694`*^-7 u^2 - 2.860505882104078`*^-7 u^3, 
    4.2105263157894735` - 0.9999999983570643` u - 
     6.7584142726673235`*^-9 u^2 + 6.784050654573548`*^-9 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` + 1.8562088801546685`*^-8 u - 
     7.635739202702465`*^-8 u^2 + 7.664702391795927`*^-8 u^3, 
    3.789473684210526` - 1.0000000004402232` u + 
     1.8109105326402641`*^-9 u^2 - 1.817779704538225`*^-9 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` - 4.973696749609309`*^-9 u + 
     2.045990134302915`*^-8 u^2 - 2.0537507461429225`*^-8 u^3, 
    3.3684210526315788` - 0.9999999998820426` u - 
     4.852322987858315`*^-10 u^2 + 4.870734926498699`*^-10 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` + 1.3326981968905547`*^-9 u - 
     5.482213345091974`*^-9 u^2 + 5.503005927757654`*^-9 u^3, 
    2.9473684210526314` - 1.0000000000316065` u + 
     1.3001688614622253`*^-10 u^2 - 1.305089369907364`*^-10 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` - 3.5709603795290947`*^-10 u + 
     1.4689520373387465`*^-9 u^2 - 1.4745162496013933`*^-9 u^3, 
    2.526315789473684` - 0.999999999991531` u - 
     3.483791033431771`*^-11 u^2 + 3.496936074043333`*^-11 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` + 9.56859549210835`*^-11 u - 
     3.935948042630136`*^-10 u^2 + 3.950590706479206`*^-10 u^3, 
    2.1052631578947367` - 1.0000000000022693` u + 
     9.334755191048316`*^-12 u^2 - 9.370282327836321`*^-12 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` - 2.564778173142444`*^-11 u + 
     1.0542717971330718`*^-10 u^2 - 1.057200329902886`*^-10 u^3, 
    1.6842105263157894` - 0.9999999999993918` u - 
     2.5011104298755527`*^-12 u^2 + 2.5082158572331537`*^-12 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` + 6.905172004614272`*^-12 u - 
     2.8113914590215253`*^-11 u^2 + 2.782106131323384`*^-11 u^3, 
    1.263157894736842` - 1.0000000000001636` u + 
     6.661338147750939`*^-13 u^2 - 6.608047442568932`*^-13 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {10.` - 1.9729062870326492`*^-12 u + 
     7.0284786475538124`*^-12 u^2 - 5.564212262646768`*^-12 u^3, 
    0.8421052631578947` - 0.9999999999999534` u - 
     1.652011860642233`*^-13 u^2 + 1.3145040611561853`*^-13 u^3, 
    0.42105263157894735`}};
```

*Plotting*

```
    fbeta1 = 40.000000000000014` - 0.6366197723675817` t
    Lta = 1/(2 Pi)*\!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Phi]r\)]\(fbeta1 \
    \[DifferentialD]t\)\)
    PicR1q = {};
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[FitRS1q], j++,
      {xi, yi, zi, dm} = ( {
          {Cos[\[Phi]r], -Sin[\[Phi]r], 0, 0},
          {Sin[\[Phi]r], Cos[\[Phi]r], 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 1, Lta},
          {0, 0, 0, 1}
         } ) . {FitRS1q[[j, 1]], FitRS1q[[j, 2]], 0, 1};
      picrq = 
       ParametricPlot3D[{xi, yi, zi}, {u, 0, FitRS1q[[j, 3]]}, {\[Phi]r, 
         0, 10*Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", MaxRecursion -> 0, 
        PlotPoints -> {2, 200}, Mesh -> False, 
        PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.8]}];
      AppendTo[PicR1q, picrq];
      ];
    Show[PicR1q, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Thank you

Comment: Presumably there is some code missing; the plot is just a 3D spiral line rather than the image that you show.

Comment: sorry. I already edit it, and  the result is as the image

Comment: I tried BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics after adding polygon "caps" from points with z=0 and z=150, but get errors that the boundary surface is not closed. Possibly due to slight mismatches between the multiple ParametricPlot3D's you combine with Show. Could you define the entire region with ParametricRegion instead?

Comment: @tad I already try use parametricRegion but get errors

Comment: Each parametric plot is a spiral ribbon. Perhaps the union of those ribbons has gaps between them that aren't visible in the Graphics3D, and that's why ParametricRegion doesn't work. What went wrong when you tried? Can you define your region as a solid? Perhaps a simpler case to make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method-1(BoundaryMeshRegion)

- We select the sample points from the parametric curves of `FitRS1q`.

```
bound = MapThread[
   ReplaceAll[#1, u -> #2] &, {FitRS1q[[;; , {1, 2}]], 
    FitRS1q[[;; , 3]]}];
ListPlot[bound, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

- We rotation and translation the `bound` points to `400` levels.

```
fbeta1 = 40.000000000000014` - 0.6366197723675817` t;
Lta = 1/(2 π)*Integrate[fbeta1, {t, 0, ϕr}];
trans[ϕr_][{x_, y_}] = 
  Evaluate[
   RotationMatrix[ϕr, {0, 0, 1}] . {x, y, 0} + {0, 0, Lta}];
levels = 400;
pts = Table[trans[t] /@ bound, {t, Subdivide[0, 10 π, levels]}];
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- We sewing the two adjacent levels by some triangles and add the bottom and upper two polygons as cover, at the end we construct a `BoundaryMeshRegion` be real 3D solid.

```
n = bound // Length;
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Catenate@
   pts, {Table[
    Transpose@{Partition[j*n + Range[n], 2, 1, 1], 
       j*n + n + Partition[Range[n], 2, 1, 1]} /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, 
        d_}} :> {Polygon[{{a, b, c}, {c, d, b}}]}, {j, 0, levels - 1}], 
   Polygon@Range@n, Polygon[(levels - 1)*n + n + Range@n]}]
```

[image]

```
bm//Volume
```

> `70722.7`.

### Method-2 (OpenCascadeShapeLoft)

```
bound = MapThread[
   ReplaceAll[#1, u -> #2] &, {FitRS1q[[;; , {1, 2}]], 
    FitRS1q[[;; , 3]]}];
fbeta1 = 40.000000000000014` - 0.6366197723675817` t;
Lta = 1/(2 π)*Integrate[fbeta1, {t, 0, ϕr}];
trans[ϕr_][{x_, y_}] = 
  Evaluate[
   RotationMatrix[ϕr, {0, 0, 1}] . {x, y, 0} + {0, 0, Lta}];
levels = 400;
pts = Table[trans[t] /@ bound, {t, Subdivide[0, 10 π, levels]}];

lines = Line@Append[#, First@#] & /@ pts;
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
shapes = OpenCascadeShape /@ lines;
loft = OpenCascadeShapeLoft[shapes, "BuildSolid" -> True];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[loft, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.2}];
bm = bmesh // BoundaryMeshRegion
bm // Volume
```

[image]

> `70876.8`.

### Method-3

Need to be improved.

We carefully set some setting in the `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
PlotPoints -> {12, 
  180}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All, Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" ->
    False}
```

```
fbeta1 = 40.000000000000014` - 0.6366197723675817` t;
Lta = 1/(2 π)*Integrate[fbeta1, {t, 0, ϕr}];
pts = MapThread[
   ReplaceAll[#1, u -> #2] &, {FitRS1q[[;; , {1, 2}]], 
    FitRS1q[[;; , 3]]}];
outline = BSplineFunction[Append[#, First@#] &@pts];
g = ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationMatrix[ϕr, {0, 0, 1}] . {Indexed[outline[u], 1], 
      Indexed[outline[u], 2], 0} + {0, 0, Lta} // Evaluate, {u, 0, 
   1}, {ϕr, 0, 10 π}, PlotPoints -> {12, 180}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Boxed -> False]
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[g, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞];
reg = RepairMesh[reg];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, 2]]
bm // Volume
FindMeshDefects[reg]
```

Comment: Thank you so Much! this is that i want. @cvgmt

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the transformation of a plot to Region is simple:

```
pp=Show[PicR1q, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
dg=DiscretizeGraphics[pp]
```

[image]

As one can see the result has head `MeshRegion`, so you can play with it using corresponding tools.

```
 RegionCentroid@dg
```

{-0.0360019, -0.000286634, 78.2525}

```
 MomentOfInertia@dg
```

{{3.09101*10^7, 2455.84, -405246.}, {2455.84, 3.09101*10^7,
10743.6}, {-405246., 10743.6, 2.76237*10^6}}

Comment: In this case, DiscretizeGraphics makes a 2D surface rather than a solid. E.g., RegionDimension for this mesh region gives 2 instead of 3. Properties such as moment of inertia are different for a surface vs. a solid.

Comment: i already did that, i want to get the centroid and moment of inertia from the solid form

Comment: @tad, as you can see, the RegionCentroid gives 3D point. The MomentOfInertia is 3x3 matrix. This is not for 2D object..

Comment: Yes the region is embedded in 3D. But this is a 3D shell where all the mass is concentrated in a zero-thickness surface. E.g., Volume gives Undefined for this region. MomentOfInertia depends on distribution of mass within a solid. E.g., MomentOfInertia of a Ball[] (solid) is not the same as a Sphere[], which is the same size as the ball but with all the mass in the surface.

Comment: yes @tad, that what i want

Comment: @tad, you are right but I clearly wrote that the region object can be processed with corresponding region-related tools. So, one can fill this shell by any way (with uniform filling or not).