Find Way to Make Solid 3D from ParametricPlot3D and Also Finding the Moment of Inertia and Center of Mass
I want to Find way to make Solid 3D from ParametricPlot3D and also finding the Moment of Inertia and Center of Mass. this is my code, hope it'll be helpfull to answer my problem. thank you.
Helix Parameter
wrap = 12*Pi; 
Ps = 136; 
Pe = 24; 
P = Ps + ((Pe - Ps)/wrap)*t; 
L = (1/(2*Pi))*Integrate[P, {t, 0, \[Phi]r}]; 
Epicycloid Curve
a = 50
b = 50/3
circle = 
  ParametricPlot[{a Sin[t], a Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] /. \[Phi]r -> 
    wrap;
min[2] = 0
0
max[2] = 2 Pi
2 \[Pi]
epicycloid = 
  ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - 
      b Cos [(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - b Sin [(a + b)/b t]}, {t, 
     min[2], max[2]}, PlotStyle -> Gray] /. \[Phi]r -> wrap;
Show[circle, epicycloid, PlotRange -> All]
Conical Rotor Surface
M = ( {
    {Cos[\[Phi]r], -Sin[\[Phi]r], 0, 0},
    {Sin[\[Phi]r], Cos[\[Phi]r], 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, L},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
   } );
{X[6], Y[6]} = {a Cos [t], a Sin[t]};
{abx, aby, abz, dm} = M . {X[6], Y[6], 0, 1};
ab3d = ParametricPlot3D[{abx, aby, abz}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Phi]r, 0, wrap}, 
   PlotPoints -> {100, 100}, Mesh -> True, PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Opacity[0.9]}];
{X[7], Y[7]} = {(a + b) Cos[t] - b Cos [(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] -
     b Sin [(a + b)/b t]};
{bcx, bcy, bcz, dm} = M . {X[7], Y[7], 0, 1};
bc3d = ParametricPlot3D[{bcx, bcy, bcz}, {t, min[2], 
    max[2]}, {\[Phi]r, 0, wrap}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, Mesh -> True,
    PlotStyle -> {Orange, Opacity[0.7]}];
Show[ab3d, bc3d, PlotRange -> All]



Similar with my previous answer (method-2). https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/306028/72111

Clear["Global`*"];
wrap = 12*Pi;
Ps = 136;
Pe = 24;
P = Ps + ((Pe - Ps)/wrap)*t;
L = (1/(2*Pi))*Integrate[P, {t, 0, ϕr}];
a = 50;
b = 50/3;
f[t_] := {(a + b) Cos[t] - b Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
    b Sin[(a + b)/b t], 0};
F[t_, ϕr_] := 
 TranslationTransform[{0, 0, L}]@*
   RotationTransform[ϕr, {0, 0, 1}]@f[t]// Evaluate;
plot = ParametricPlot3D[
  F[t, ϕr]//Evaluate, {ϕr, 0, wrap}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {400, 400}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{0, wrap}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}]


pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> pts, -1][[1]];
polys = Cases[plot, GraphicsGroup[data_] :> data, -1][[1, 1]];
lines = Cases[plot, _Line, -1];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, 
  Polygon[Join[lines /. Line[pts_] :> Rest@pts, First@First@polys]]]


{RegionCentroid[reg], MomentOfInertia[reg]}


Clear["Global`*"];
wrap = 12*Pi;
Ps = 136;
Pe = 24;
P = Ps + ((Pe - Ps)/wrap)*t;
L = (1/(2*Pi))*Integrate[P, {t, 0, ϕr}];
a = 50;
b = 50/3;
f[t_] := {(a + b) Cos[t] - b Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
    b Sin[(a + b)/b t], 0};
F[t_, ϕr_] := 
  TranslationTransform[{0, 0, L}]@*
     RotationTransform[ϕr, {0, 0, 1}]@f[t] // Evaluate;
ptss = Table[
   F[u, θ], {θ, Rest@Subdivide[0, wrap, 800]}, {u, 
    Rest@Subdivide[0, 2 π, 90]}];
{m, n, p} = Dimensions[ptss];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Catenate[
   ptss], {Table[
    Polygon[{{#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]}, {#1[[2]], #1[[1]], \
#2[[2]]}}] & @@@ 
     Thread@{Partition[Range[1, n] + j*n, 2, 1, 1], 
       Partition[Range[1, n] + (j + 1)*n, 2, 1, 1]}, {j, 0, m - 2}], 
   Polygon[Range[1, n]], Polygon[Range[1, n] + (m - 1)*n]}]
bm // Volume



(+1) no OpenCascade today ;-)

@user21  Thanks!  use OpenCascadeLink next  time :)  Seems similar with another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287856/72111

@cvgmt hi, i want to ask questions regardless of the question above. how do we make a parametricplot3d into solid shape if the parametricplot 3d is built by combining multiple parametricplot 3d with different of t[max] and t[min], at least there is 2 different t[max] and t[min].
